Understanding Feasibility, Constraints in the Lagrange Dual Function: A Query on Boyd's Least-Squares Example
I am confused by a basic problem with the Lagrange dual function. As Boyd states,
$g(\lambda, \mu) = \underset{\scriptsize \text{$x \in D$}}{inf}L(x, \lambda, \mu) = \underset{\scriptsize \text{$x \in D$}}{inf}\left(f_0(x)+\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_if_i(x)+\sum_{i=1}^p\mu_ih_i(x)\right)$,
where x belongs to the feasible set D. However, in his example of the least-squares solution of linear equations, the objective is $x^Tx$, and the constraint is $Ax=b$. Thus, the Lagrange function is $x^Tx+\mu^T(Ax-b)$. Taking its derivative yields $\nabla_xL(x, \mu) = 2x+A^T\mu$. Boyd then sets this derivative equal to zero to solve for , obtaining $-(\dfrac{1}{2})A^T\mu$. However, my question is how does he know that this  belongs to the feasible set D? Why does he seem to ignore the constraints?
The relevant video content can be found in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_SuSVZnrT0&list=PLoROMvodv4rMJqxxviPa4AmDClvcbHi6h&index=7, from minute 40:00 to minute 59:30.

Because the constraints $Ax=b$ have already been relaxed, and merged to the Lagrangian function as a kind of penalty term. So when you set the gradient of Lagrangian w.r.t. x to zero, no constraints are there.
